# how to keep alerting a message if you pressed the spacebar

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i make the page keep alerting a message if i pressed the spacebar once. When I run my code, if you pressed the space bar, an alert will pop up once saying "you pressed the spacebar." How do I make it so that if I press the spacebar once an alert will keep popping up saying that i pressed the spacebar.

code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(keycode == 32){
            alert("you pressed the spacebar")
        }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bqvnp6Lb/

Comment: You want alert message to be persistent like if a spacebar has been pushed once ?

Comment: @Ronnie848, Just to let you know, the client browser may ask them if they would like to disable the alert messages if they keep popping up over and over on the same page. If they choose to disable the alerts then they can press the space bar all they want and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Add an infinite while loop:

```
if (keycode == 32) {
    while (true) {
        alert("you pressed the spacebar");
    }
}
```

Comment: But this will completely block to do anything else. alert will come untill the user close the tab itself.That's not a good idea. i DON'T KNOW WHY op WANT SOMETHING LIKE THAT

Comment: It will not allow you to close the alert even with mouse click

Comment: @AbhiAndhariya thats what the OP wants, u skrub

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**setInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).`3000` is the time interval in millisecond. It will keep on firing at every 3 secs. If you want to remove the setInterval you can use `clearInterval()`

```js
 $(document).keydown(function(event) { //jQuery code to recognize a keydown event
      var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
      if (keycode == 32) {
        setInterval(function() {
          alert("Hello");
        }, 3000);
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: jquery is missing

Answer (score 0):

Please check this, You can call event on the body. It's working.

```js
$('body').keyup(function(e){
   
   if(e.keyCode == 32){
       // user has pressed space
       alert('You hit spacebar');
       console.log('You hit spacebar');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what do you want to achieve here. but, you can do it using a recursive function call. But I must warn you that if you do this, the alert will keep coming every 2 seconds and stay until you press **"ok"** everytime.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).keydown(function(event){  //jQuery code to recognize a keydown event
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if(keycode == 32){
                recAlert()
            }
        });

    function recAlert(){
        alert("you pressed the spacebar")
        setTimeout( function(){
            recAlert();
        }, 2000);

    }

</script>
```